# HighCharts Column Overlapping

Tags: highcharts

How do I get HighCharts not to overlap columns in this chart? I have tried all sorts of options. What I would like is for highcharts to set the widths evenly depending on the number data elements in the series, the more the narrower.'

I have specified width: 300 to force the columns to overlap just to show what is happening in narrow chart and only add a few data elements.

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      width: 300,
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      data: [
        [102.0, 66815.0],
        [96.0, 77760.0],
        [90.0, 68710.0],
        [84.0, 69452.5],
        [78.0, 48807.5],
        [72.0, 35472.5],
        [66.0, 24595.0],
        [60.0, 17790.0],
        [54.0, 18010.0],
        [48.0, 5635.0]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a0kjogh1/3/

Answer (score 0):

Data should be sorted before you put it into the chart. You receive the [error](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) in the console.

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
    return a[0] > b[0];
  });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/a0kjogh1/4/